# Add .properties file to output folder of Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flexbuilder

In our current project we use .properties files as external files. When building our project the properties files are not added to the bin debug (output folder). Xml files are added without any problem.

Does anybody know how I can add the .properties extension to a kind of exclusion filter list or something, so flash builder will add this files to my output folder instead of ignoring them?

(I'm using Flash builder beta 2 as plugin for Eclipse)

Thanks a lot.

Wannes

Comment: Why do you want your .properties file in the output folder anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Remove .properties from the exclusion list under Window > Preferences > Flash Builder > File Exclusions > File Extensions.

This should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Properties, under Flex Compiler there is a checkbox that allows you to "Copy non-embedded files to output folder".

That should work.

Comment: That is what you expect. But for some reason .properties files are not copied to the output folder. Other files like xml files are added...

Comment: Is the .properties file inside the src folder?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for that would be to change the **"properties"** suffix to **"xml"**

It will auto copy your files

I didn't find a quick solution for that also, but I don't have a lot of time to waste trying to find bug fixes for Adobe :)