# Adobe air native installer is not including .class files and .properties files

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have some files in my src directory, some are .class files (Java class files) and some are .properties files, when I create the Adobe air native installer these files are not included. Why is that? How can I work around that?

Also it excludes .mxml files, but that's good. I'm sure that's related, how to change what it includes or excludes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly not sure why it's excluding those on you.  But you can right click the project in the project navigator panel, go to properties, on the left side navigation select "Flex Build Packaging", click the "Package Contents" tab on the right, make sure the files you want are selected.  If they aren't there I would guess somehow these files aren't being seen in the source path, check that under Flex Build Path -> Source Path.

EDIT:

Found this as a duplicate, following the steps to go to window preferences and remove the exclusions seems to have worked.

[Add .properties file to output folder of Flex project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644976/add-properties-file-to-output-folder-of-flex-project)

Comment: Hi, the files are in the source path, they appear selected in the "Flex Build Packaging" its just when I get to the last step in the native installer packaging they are not selected and they are not available for selection. In fact, they are not even available for selection in the last step. You can try it yourself, create a new Air project, add a .properties text file in src folder and try to do a native installer, look at the packaging on the last step.

Comment: @Phil out of curiosity what OS are you running, does it also not show SomeObject.class files in there or only the .properties files, I'm wondering if the system or eclipse is thinking those are hidden files that shouldn't be a part of the package.  I have an AIR app here I used for making a custom screen-saver and it loads the data to show out of an XML file that i included in the source and it ends up in the exe and sub-sequently the extracted program files folder for me. I posted mine here as an example, is it a problem with this project? http://www.shaunhusain.com/QuotesScreensaver.fxp

Comment: It does NOT show class files and .properties files, but it does show .xml files. (in the last step of the installer). On Windows. Try putting in a test.properties file

Comment: @Phil absolutely see what you're saying about a test.properties file going to try some more things out to see what's going on

Comment: @Phil edited my post above with a link to the same issue posted on stack overflow, that seems to have worked fine for me, see it in the bin-debug folder as well as in the list of package contents now

Comment: Thats a really non-obvious way to package the files! it should be in some xml file saying what is or is not in the packaging. Anyway, you win the prize!